# How to make <div> to fill the remaining height without using flexbox?

Tags: html, css

I have a html layout like this:

```
,-------------.
|,-----------.|
|| child 1   ||
|`-----------'|
|,-----------.|
|| child 2   ||
||           ||
||           ||
||           ||
||           ||
|`-----------'|
`-------------'
```

The container is given a height value, say `100vh`, and `child 1` has a fixed height. I want the `child 2` to automatically fill the remaining height.

I know there is a flexbox solution:

```
.container { 
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.child-1 {
    flex-shrink: 0;
    flex-grow: 0;
}
.child-2 {
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

The solution works as alone, but if I want a third child `child 3` inside `child 2` with a `height: 100%`, it fails. I need to make `child 2` flex and set `child 3` to `flex-grow: 1`.

This kind of flex-inheriting become really frustrating as the nesting goes deeper. Also it violates "Seperation of Concern" since the DOM structure only works when all the nodes are properly set to `display: flex`.

Below is jsfiddle demonstrating the problem.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.child-1 {
  height: 50px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-grow: 0;
}

.child-2 {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.child-3 {
  height: 80%;
}


/* irrelevant styles like background-color etc. */

.container.irrelevant {
  width: 100px;
  background: green;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.child-1.irrelevant {
  background: red;
}

.child-2.irrelevant {
  background: magenta;
}

.child-3.irrelevant {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container irrelevant">
  <div class="child-1 irrelevant">
    Child 1
  </div>
  <div class="child-2 irrelevant">
    Child 2<br> Seems like it works
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container irrelevant">
  <div class="child-1 irrelevant">
    Child 1
  </div>
  <div class="child-2 irrelevant">
    Child 2
    <div class="child-3 irrelevant">
      But it doesn't, child 3 should fill 80% height of the child 2.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `height: 100%` to child 2.

you can use  CSS `grid` also but it's not supported in all browsers.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.child-1 {
  height: 50px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-grow: 0;
}

.child-2 {
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: calc(100% - 50px); /* add this line */
}

.child-3 {
  height: 80%;
}


/* irrelevant styles like background-color etc. */

.container.irrelevant {
  width: 100px;
  background: green;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.child-1.irrelevant {
  background: red;
}

.child-2.irrelevant {
  background: magenta;
}

.child-3.irrelevant {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container irrelevant">
  <div class="child-1 irrelevant">
    Child 1
  </div>
  <div class="child-2 irrelevant">
    Child 2<br> Seems like it works
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container irrelevant">
  <div class="child-1 irrelevant">
    Child 1
  </div>
  <div class="child-2 irrelevant">
    Child 2
    <div class="child-3 irrelevant">
      But it doesn't, child 3 should fill 80% height of the child 2.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this way the height  of the second is more the remind height, so you have to scoll.. you make it 100% of the page although part of it already in use.

Answer (score 4):

Oh you can use calc for this. Something like this;

```
.child-2 { height: calc(100vh - 100px); }
```

Assuming the fixed height for `.child-1` is `100px`.

If you want something more dynamic use @patelarpan's solution, but this is quick and easy (and not dirty).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `.child-3` cannot properly calculate parents height unless it has set `flex-basis`. So you can fix this by using `flex: 1` on `child-2` [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/fvkg3cp4/2/) or by just adding `flex-basis: 0%` [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/fvkg3cp4/3/) which is the same thing that the browser will do if you use `flex: 1`.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.child-1 {
  flex: 1;
  height: 50px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-grow: 0;
}

.child-2 {
  flex: 1;
}

.child-3 {
  height: 80%;
}


/* irrelevant styles like background-color etc. */

.container.irrelevant {
  width: 100px;
  background: green;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.child-1.irrelevant {
  background: red;
}

.child-2.irrelevant {
  background: magenta;
}

.child-3.irrelevant {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container irrelevant">
  <div class="child-1 irrelevant">
    Child 1
  </div>
  <div class="child-2 irrelevant">
    Child 2<br> Seems like it works
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container irrelevant">
  <div class="child-1 irrelevant">
    Child 1
  </div>
  <div class="child-2 irrelevant">
    Child 2
    <div class="child-3 irrelevant">
      But it doesn't, child 3 should fill 80% height of the child 2.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```